# CSS custom sidebar adjusting width based on state

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following element:

```
<div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col bg-background overflow-hidden">
  <div className=" bg-yellow-300 flex flex-1">
    <Sidebar />
    <div id="non-sidebar" className=" bg-black min-h-screen w-full">
      <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col py-20">
       // stuff in here but not important for question 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with Sidebar component:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [sidebarDisplay, setSidebarDisplay] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleSetSidebarDisplay = () => {
    setSidebarDisplay((display) => !display);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className={`${
        sidebarDisplay ? "w-96" : "w-0"
      } bg-primary transition-width duration-500 ease-in-out`}
    >
      <div className={`relative h-full flex flex-col items-center`}>
        <div className="w-4 absolute top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 -right-[21.8px] -rotate-90">
          <Button
            onClick={handleSetSidebarDisplay}
            className="rounded-t-none px-5 py-0 h-7 w-32 z-10 cursor-pointer"
          >
            My tasks
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I designed it so that when sidebar is w-0 (sidebarDisplay is false), the non-sidebar component will adjust and take up all the space that sidebar was and vise versa.

The problem is, when I want to add a child to sidebar, I also have to base its width on the sidebarDisplay prop like so:

```
<Button className={`${sidebarDisplay ? "w-full" : "w-0"}`}>
  Add New Task
</Button>
```

which I'll have to do for every child component and doesn't feel right.

I know I can make the sidebar open and close above the other div and avoid this problem altogether but I like the effect of both components adjusting to each other and want to use it in the future.

Is there a better way to do this without having the sidebar in front of the "non-sidebar" component?

Is there a better implementation for this type of sidebar?

Comment: Good question. In Plesk its UI they use a sidebar in wide mode and a expandable top bar in small mode

Comment: what UI framefork are you using? if any